# Filter on WMI. If xp then proceed otherwise fail

Tags: powershell

The if condition works until I try to add the last portion of the line in there.  I want it to look at the value of the operating system and if it is equal to 5.* then proceed with the statement. Otherwise fail.

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $Machine
$OSVER = $OS.VERSION
if (($IEVersion -like '8*') -and (($Machine -like '[NCI]*') -or ($Machine -like '[RXPC]*') -or ($Machine -like '[RXCO]*') -or ($Machine -like '[MW]*') -or ($Machine -like '[SMPC]*') -or ($Machine -like '[MTPC]*')) -and ($OSVER -like '5.*'))
{
    Write-Host "Do something here"
}
    else
{
Write-Host "Do nothing on the machine"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did was put the WMI call outside of the IF statement.  All works as expected.  I have updated the code above.